# Wordpress Category Post List Plugin Customisation

Tags: php, html, wordpress, plugins, categories

I'm hoping you can help me with this conundrum...

I'm trying to customise the [Wordpress Category Post List plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-category-posts-list/) so that it lists the posts categories below the post heading in the shortcode.

```
<a class="wp-cpl-info" href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>" title="<?php echo __('Permalink to: ', $trans) . $post->post_title; ?>">
<h2><?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?></h2>
<span class="cross">X</span>
<span class="details"><?php $categories = get_categories( $args ); ?></span>
</a>
```

I'm trying to find the Wordpress php function that goes where the current code sits (this was just a guess). The rest of the plugin output code is an indication of what's possible...

```
<?php if($op['show_date'] == 'true' || $op['show_author'] == 'true' || $op['show_comments'] == 'true') : ?>
<div class="wp-cpl-sc-meta">
    <p>
        <?php if($op['show_date'] == 'true') : ?>
        <span class="wp-cpl-sc-date"><?php echo __('Posted on ', $trans) . date('M jS, Y', strtotime($post->post_date)) . ' '; ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($op['show_author'] == 'true') : ?>
        <span class="wp-cpl-sc-author"><?php echo __(' - By ', $trans) . '<a href="' . get_the_author_meta('user_url', $post->post_author) . '">' . get_the_author_meta('display_name', $post->post_author) . '</a> '; ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($op['show_comments'] == 'true') : ?>
        <span class="wp-cpl-sc-comment"><?php echo ' - <a href="' . get_comments_link($post->ID) . '">' . $post->comment_count . ' ' . __ngettext('Comment', 'Comments', $post->comment_count, $trans) . '</a>' ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </p>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($op['show_excerpt'] == 'true') : ?>
<div class="wp-cpl-sc-entry">
    <p>
        <?php echo (('true' == $op['optional_excerpt'] && $post->post_excerpt != '')? $post->post_excerpt : itgdb_wp_cpl_loader::shorten_string($post->post_content, $op['excerpt_length'])); ?>
    </p>
    <?php if('' != $op['read_more']) : ?>
    <p class="wp-cpl-sc-readmore">
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><?php echo $op['read_more']; ?></a>
    </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

All of this code belongs to the wp_cpl_output_gen.php code in the includes folder for the plugin.

Hopefully this all makes sense! Basically I'm creating something that looks like [this](http://samking.co/) so I need to be able to display the categories.

Thanks heaps!

Kathryn

Comment: Are you sure you posted the write url for the example?  I don't see anything on that page that looks like what you are asking

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You don't need to include signature in your post - your user card is added automatically. Read [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) for more details.

Comment: Thanks @Artemix. Essentially I just need the WP snippet of code that calls the categories - in the same way it does for the post title, author or date

Like this but for the categories:

<span class="wp-cpl-sc-date"><?php echo __('Posted on ', $trans) . date('M jS, Y', strtotime($post->post_date)) . ' '; ?></span>

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out, and sorry if the question was convoluted, I didn't know exactly what I was looking for until it dawned on me...

Basically I needed the category equivalent of:

```
<?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?>
```

Which as it turns out isn't complicated - see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category for reference - and becomes:

```
<?php echo get_the_category($post->ID); ?>
```

Thanks guys!